# Function call and file path confusion

Tags: python, function, pycharm, call, filepath

I have two scripts, `main` and `statistics`. In one script, `main`, several functions from the other script, `statistics`, are called. The code is as follows.

```
if initial_action == "get_portfolio_statistics":
    statistics.get_portfolio_status()
    statistics.get_current_securities()
    statistics.get_open_trades()
```

Of course, the functions match as far as calling names go, and my IDE (PyCharm) is not giving any warnings. Tests have, refactor after refactor, turned up the fundamentally same error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/stuff/dev/!projects+repositories/RYZ/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import statistics
  File "G:\stuff\dev\!projects+repositories\RYZ\statistics.py", line 1, in 
   <module>
    import main
  File "G:\stuff\dev\!projects+repositories\RYZ\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    statistics.get_portfolio_status()
AttributeError: module 'statistics' has no attribute 'get_portfolio_status'
```

There are, however, a few intriguing recurrences that have popped up. First of all, in some cases, for no identifiable reason, the tests check out when the function names are changed, however, the results are not consistent with further tests. Second of all, the use of back/forward slashes in the file paths are not consistent, with a `G:/` with the first call, and then `G:\` for the two latest calls, though the first and latest calls are referring to the same file.

My question is whether this error is a matter of function naming, a matter of file path inconsistencies, a matter of cross-imports, or due to the fact that the functions being called are not housed in a class.

Project Structure:

```
ryz server backend (RYZ directory)
 - main.py
 - statistics.py
```

Import Structure:

```
# in main.py
import statistics

# in statistics.py
import main
```

`statistics.py` Structure:

```
<imports...>
def get_portfolio_status():
    <code>
def get_current_securities():
    <code>
def get_open_trades():
    <code>
```

Comment: Better use `/` because it is more crosplatform

Comment: Could you add more info, like structure folder, where those modules exist, how do you make import your `statistic` module

Comment: @marni like that?

Comment: @E.Maguire What is the structure of your `statistics` file?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet it's because of the cross-import. Try to move anything that statistics.py require to that file and then import into and call from main.py.

Your function naming is normal.

I wouldn't worry about the mix of slashes. However, if you're constructing a path yourself, use the os module:

```
import os
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dir', 'filename')
```

This will ensure that  you get a path suited to your platform.